# Is there a python code for image data augmentation for the whole data set?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, data-augmentation

I'm working on CNN(Convolution Neural Network) for image classification problem. I have a data set of 1000 images, this images are not enough to fit the model I have designed and I want to increase the number of images before training the CNN. How to augment my data set by using python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use keras's [`ImageDataGenerator`](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/) class. This class has many interesting features to generate augmented image dataset. This class can be used to augment the dataset from folder also.
E.g.

```py
generator = ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range=20,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)
```

More information on the `ImageDataGenerator` class is found [here](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/).

Now you can use this generator with your keras model as follows

```py
model.fit_generator(generator.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size= ... ),
                    steps_per_epoch= .... , epochs= ... )
```

To generate augmented dataset from folder use `flow_from_directory` method of the class.

```py
model.fit_generator(generator.flow_from_directory(directory, target_size=(64, 64), batch_size= ...),steps_per_epoch= .... , epochs= ... )
```

Comment: hey @Mitiku thanks a lot to your comment and how could I know how many images are generated ?

Comment: Number of images generated for all `epochs == batch_size * steps_per_epoch * epochs`, Number of image generated for epoch is `batch_size * steps_per_epoch` and Number of images generated for batch is `batch_size`. But why you need the information any way?

Answer (score 0):

This is a built-in in tensorflow. Look up the documentation of [tf.image](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image)

For example you can use the following functions by using `tf.Dataset.map`:

- `tf.image.random_flip_up_down`
- `tf.image.random_flip_left_right`
- `tf.image.random_contrast`
- `tf.image.random_brightness`